# How can I retrieve the Id of the selected column in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid

I have built this grid using ag-grid:
[image]

I want to know when the user clicks on a specific cell the following:
- RowId
- ColumnId (The field attribute in the columns definitions)

So far I have only managed to collect the rowId this way:

> Relevant html code:

```
  (rowClicked)="getRowId($event)"
```

> Relevant TypeScript code:

```
  getRowId(chosenRow) {
    console.log('chosenRow.node: ', chosenRow.node); 
}
```

I am wondering if I can use a similar approach to detect which column the user has just selected?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply listening to the grid cell clicked event as below.

```
 this.gridOptions.onCellClicked = ((event: CellClickedEvent) => {
     const rowId = event.rowIndex;
     const colId = event.column.colId;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  (cellClicked)="updateDepartementsDropDownList($event);"
```

typescript :

```
 updateDepartementsDropDownList(params) {
    const colId = params.column.getId();
    console.log('colId: ', colId);

  }
```